# Flexcan implementation in K66f microcontroller

Tags: c, microcontroller, can-bus, nxp-microcontroller

I am trying to implement a flexcan communication using a k66f micro controller. As an initial step I just want to send a message through the tx pin. I am basing my program on an example from NXP.

I am very new to C and specially to micro controller programming. The code I run gets stuck in the following line:

```
/* Wait until CAN Message send out. */
while (!FLEXCAN_GetMbStatusFlags(base, 1 << mbIdx))
{ 
}
```

I don't know how exactly the meaning of the code since as I understand, FLEXCAN_GetMbStatusFlags is not a function.

Thanks in advance.

the micro controller is nxp's k66f.

Edit: This is the example

```
#include "fsl_debug_console.h"
#include "fsl_flexcan.h"
#include "board.h"

#include "pin_mux.h"
#include "clock_config.h"
/*******************************************************************************
 * Definitions
 ******************************************************************************/
#define EXAMPLE_CAN CAN0
#define EXAMPLE_CAN_CLKSRC kCLOCK_BusClk
#define EXAMPLE_FLEXCAN_IRQn CAN0_ORed_Message_buffer_IRQn
#define EXAMPLE_FLEXCAN_IRQHandler CAN0_ORed_Message_buffer_IRQHandler
#define RX_MESSAGE_BUFFER_NUM (8)
#define TX_MESSAGE_BUFFER_NUM (9)
int status;
/*******************************************************************************
 * Prototypes
 ******************************************************************************/

/*******************************************************************************
 * Variables
 ******************************************************************************/
volatile bool rxComplete = false;
flexcan_frame_t txFrame, rxFrame;

/*******************************************************************************
 * Code
 ******************************************************************************/

/*!
 * @brief Main function
 */
int main(void)
{
    flexcan_config_t flexcanConfig;
    flexcan_rx_mb_config_t mbConfig;

    /* Initialize board hardware. */
    BOARD_InitPins();
    BOARD_BootClockRUN();
    BOARD_InitDebugConsole();

    PRINTF("\r\n==FlexCAN loopback functional example -- Start.==\r\n\r\n");

    /* Init FlexCAN module. */
    /*
     * flexcanConfig.clkSrc = kFLEXCAN_ClkSrcOsc;
     * flexcanConfig.baudRate = 125000U;
     * flexcanConfig.maxMbNum = 16;
     * flexcanConfig.enableLoopBack = false;
     * flexcanConfig.enableSelfWakeup = false;
     * flexcanConfig.enableIndividMask = false;
     * flexcanConfig.enableDoze = false;
     */
    FLEXCAN_GetDefaultConfig(&flexcanConfig);
    flexcanConfig.clkSrc = kFLEXCAN_ClkSrcPeri;
    //flexcanConfig.enableLoopBack = true;
    FLEXCAN_Init(EXAMPLE_CAN, &flexcanConfig, CLOCK_GetFreq(EXAMPLE_CAN_CLKSRC));

    /* Setup Rx Message Buffer. */
    mbConfig.format = kFLEXCAN_FrameFormatStandard;
    mbConfig.type = kFLEXCAN_FrameTypeData;
    mbConfig.id = FLEXCAN_ID_STD(0x123);
    FLEXCAN_SetRxMbConfig(EXAMPLE_CAN, RX_MESSAGE_BUFFER_NUM, &mbConfig, true);

    /* Setup Tx Message Buffer. */
    FLEXCAN_SetTxMbConfig(EXAMPLE_CAN, TX_MESSAGE_BUFFER_NUM, true);

    /* Enable Rx Message Buffer interrupt. */
    FLEXCAN_EnableMbInterrupts(EXAMPLE_CAN, 1 << RX_MESSAGE_BUFFER_NUM);
    EnableIRQ(EXAMPLE_FLEXCAN_IRQn);

    /* Prepare Tx Frame for sending. */
    txFrame.format = kFLEXCAN_FrameFormatStandard;
    txFrame.type = kFLEXCAN_FrameTypeData;
    txFrame.id = FLEXCAN_ID_STD(0x123);
    txFrame.length = 8;
    txFrame.dataWord0 = CAN_WORD0_DATA_BYTE_0(0x11) | CAN_WORD0_DATA_BYTE_1(0x22) | CAN_WORD0_DATA_BYTE_2(0x33) |
                        CAN_WORD0_DATA_BYTE_3(0x44);
    txFrame.dataWord1 = CAN_WORD1_DATA_BYTE_4(0x55) | CAN_WORD1_DATA_BYTE_5(0x66) | CAN_WORD1_DATA_BYTE_6(0x77) |
                        CAN_WORD1_DATA_BYTE_7(0x88);

    /* Send data through Tx Message Buffer using polling function. */
    status=FlEXCAN_TransferSendBlocking(EXAMPLE_CAN, TX_MESSAGE_BUFFER_NUM, &txFrame);
    PRINTF("status= %d \r\n", status);
    PRINTF("Send message from MB%d to MB%d\r\n", TX_MESSAGE_BUFFER_NUM, RX_MESSAGE_BUFFER_NUM);
    PRINTF("tx word0 = 0x%x\r\n", txFrame.dataWord0);
    PRINTF("tx word1 = 0x%x\r\n", txFrame.dataWord1);


    /* Waiting for Message receive finish. */
    while (!rxComplete)
    {
    }

    PRINTF("\r\nReceved message from MB%d\r\n", RX_MESSAGE_BUFFER_NUM);
    PRINTF("rx word0 = 0x%x\r\n", rxFrame.dataWord0);
    PRINTF("rx word1 = 0x%x\r\n", rxFrame.dataWord1);

    /* Stop FlexCAN Send & Receive. */
    FLEXCAN_DisableMbInterrupts(EXAMPLE_CAN, 1 << RX_MESSAGE_BUFFER_NUM);

    PRINTF("\r\n==FlexCAN loopback functional example -- Finish.==\r\n");

    while (1)
    {
        __WFI();
    }
}

void EXAMPLE_FLEXCAN_IRQHandler(void)
{
    /* If new data arrived. */
    if (FLEXCAN_GetMbStatusFlags(EXAMPLE_CAN, 1 << RX_MESSAGE_BUFFER_NUM))
    {
        FLEXCAN_ClearMbStatusFlags(EXAMPLE_CAN, 1 << RX_MESSAGE_BUFFER_NUM);
        FLEXCAN_ReadRxMb(EXAMPLE_CAN, RX_MESSAGE_BUFFER_NUM, &rxFrame);
        rxComplete = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you initialized your CAN module and Mailboxes?

Comment: I think so, its the example code provided on the kinetis SDK, so if the loopback is enabled everything seems to work. If I disable it, I can't make it work with the actual can bus ports. Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: Ohh!! In that case, Have you connected 120Ohm Terminators? Is there any other active node on the bus? For CAN, You should have at least two active nodes on the bus and 120Ohm terminator resistor.

Comment: I did use 130ohm resistor (didn't have 120). Now it seems to send the message. Thanks!